# Proper use of "whom"

Tags: word-usage

Have I used "whom" correctly in the following sentence?
Rarely a day goes by here that I don’t witness this core value manifesting itself in a myriad of thoughtful, sincere, acts of kindness toward our residents, many of whom have enriched our lives beyond measure.

Comment: "Whom" is used for referring to living things. In case of non-living things, or abstract nouns, "which" is used. So, if you're referring to "acts of kindness", then it should be "which". If you're referring to people ("residents"), then you've used "whom" correctly.

Comment: On a side note, I think it should be "Rarely a day goes by here **when** I don't ...", instead of "... that I don't ...". I'm not sure, though. Maybe somebody might clear this up.

Answer (score 1):

You use *whom* as an object and *who* as a subject.

At first glance, it may appear that in the sentence "many of whom have enriched...", *whom* is acting as a subject, but it isn't.

In this sentence, *whom* is acting as the object of the preposition *of* in the phrase "many of whom", and "many of whom" is the subject.

So, ***whom* is the proper form here**.